# Step implementation missing for: XXX-XXXXXX-XXXXX while running feature file

Tags: cypress

I am working in Cypress with BDD, when I run my feature file using test runner I get "Step implementation missing for"

[image]

My step definition file is in the same location where other step def files are resided. I added my feature file in the cypress.json as other feature files like  "**/myfeaturefile.feature. Also I imported import {Given, When, Then} from "cypress-cucumber-preprocessor/steps" in my step def file but no luck. I tried all most all solutions provided in the google but could not able to fix. I need the solution to run my test cases

I am not sure what is the issue any help would be appreciated

Thanks

Comment: can you post your feature file, step definition file, and also folder structure of your project?

Comment: Project Folder
-->Integration
     -->.fetaure files, 
    StepDefFolder-->stepdef.spe,js, 
 PageObject-->coomonpagesile.js

This is my folder structure